# Random poses for a robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, robot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I need to finish a project for an internship but I am not really sure how to do it. Can you check it out?

1. Solution launched
2. User inputs number of poses to test
3. Poses are generated for workspace volume
4. Poses are tested to be reachable by robot
   a. ROSINFO outputs current pose details:
   i. Pose Number
   ii. Cartesian pose details
   iii. Is pose reachable by robot? (successful or unsuccessful)
5. Results are saved to CSV file

So basically, they want me to make a robot arm and give 100 random poses to it and do the rest. I am sure I can write a python script to generate the poses and publish it (Yeah but how?) And I don't know how to use ROSINFO and how to save results to a CSV file... And I don't want to use any simulation to create those poses such as MoveIt etc.

So any source suggestion or any kind of help from all...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298361/random-poses-for-a-robotic-arm/) by [Hank470](https://answers.ros.org/users/36618/hank470/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With all respect, this is homework and you should be able to solve it by reading the Publisher/Subscriber and MoveIt tutorials attentively. MoveIt is the easiest way to check the reachability of a pose. You will need to invest a few hours of study or ask an actual question if you're stuck.

You might also want to read this for general culture. Good luck: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2